# DownloadFileAsync is not working/called. It is skipped to DownloadCompleted even there is no downloaded file

Tags: vb.net, webclient, basic, downloadfileasync

I have problem. I'm using Visual Studio 2013 (Visual Basic) and on my computer everything works fine but on other doesn't.

Example: client1.DownloadFileAsync is not getting called and client1_DownloadCompleted is called even there is no downloaded file. Why it is just skipped !?

Code (On DownloadButton_Click): `

```
            AddHandler client1.DownloadProgressChanged, AddressOf client_ProgressChanged
            AddHandler client1.DownloadFileCompleted, AddressOf client1_DownloadCompleted
            AddHandler client2.DownloadProgressChanged, AddressOf client_ProgressChanged
            AddHandler client2.DownloadFileCompleted, AddressOf client2_DownloadCompleted
            AddHandler client3.DownloadProgressChanged, AddressOf client_ProgressChanged
            AddHandler client3.DownloadFileCompleted, AddressOf client3_DownloadCompleted
            AddHandler client4.DownloadProgressChanged, AddressOf client_ProgressChanged
            AddHandler client4.DownloadFileCompleted, AddressOf client1_DownloadCompleted
            AddHandler client5.DownloadProgressChanged, AddressOf client_ProgressChanged
            AddHandler client5.DownloadFileCompleted, AddressOf client2_DownloadCompleted
            AddHandler client6.DownloadProgressChanged, AddressOf client_ProgressChanged
            AddHandler client6.DownloadFileCompleted, AddressOf client3_DownloadCompleted


            If CheckBox7.Checked Then
                odkoliko = odkoliko + 1
                Label8.Text = "Popravlja se " & koliko & "/" & odkoliko & " stavka!"
                client5.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/7wq47s49aw5qrps/Obrisi%20PMF%20Novi%20Sad.lnk"), filePath5)
            End If
            If CheckBox4.Checked Then
                odkoliko = odkoliko + 1
                Label8.Text = "Popravlja se " & koliko & "/" & odkoliko & " stavka!"
                client4.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/69q4pd281ka3lmf/Repair.exe"), filePath4)
            End If
            If CheckBox2.Checked Then
                odkoliko = odkoliko + 1
                Label8.Text = "Popravlja se " & koliko & "/" & odkoliko & " stavka!"
                client1.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/u4iy3katgl394wf/PMF%20Novi%20Sad%20UPDATE.exe"), filePath1)
            End If
            If CheckBox5.Checked Then
                odkoliko = odkoliko + 1
                Label8.Text = "Popravlja se " & koliko & "/" & odkoliko & " stavka!"
                client2.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/tuy0zspy1i1y84u/chatroom.html"), filePath2)
            End If
            If CheckBox3.Checked Then
                odkoliko = odkoliko + 1
                Label8.Text = "Popravlja se " & koliko & "/" & odkoliko & " stavka!"
                client6.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/1n7oe7d1ms72qo3/Update.exe"), filePath6)
            End If
    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub client_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs)

End Sub

Private Sub client1_DownloadCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs)
    koliko = koliko + 1
    Label8.Text = "Popravlja se " & koliko & "/" & odkoliko & " stavka!"
    AllDownloadFinished()
End Sub

Private Sub client2_DownloadCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs)
    koliko = koliko + 1
    Label8.Text = "Popravlja se " & koliko & "/" & odkoliko & " stavka!"
    AllDownloadFinished()
End Sub

Private Sub client3_DownloadCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs)
    koliko = koliko + 1
    Label8.Text = "Popravlja se " & koliko & "/" & odkoliko & " stavka!"
    AllDownloadFinished()
End Sub

Private Sub client4_DownloadCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs)
    koliko = koliko + 1
    Label8.Text = "Popravlja se " & koliko & "/" & odkoliko & " stavka!"
    AllDownloadFinished()
End Sub

Private Sub client5_DownloadCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs)
    koliko = koliko + 1
    Label8.Text = "Popravlja se " & koliko & "/" & odkoliko & " stavka!"
    AllDownloadFinished()
End Sub

Private Sub client6_DownloadCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs)
    koliko = koliko + 1
    Label8.Text = "Popravlja se " & koliko & "/" & odkoliko & " stavka!"
    AllDownloadFinished()
End Sub

Public Sub AllDownloadFinished()
    If koliko > odkoliko Then
        Label6.Text = "GOTOVO!"
        ProgressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Continuous
        ProgressBar1.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 0
        Panel1.Visible = False
        Panel2.Visible = False
        Panel3.Visible = True
    End If
End Sub`
```

As I said on my computer that code works perfectly but on my friend's doesn't. Maybe the problem is not in the code than in .NET Framwork, Visual c++ Redistributable, Web Deployment or some other Microsoft apps that needs to be installed !?

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't checking for async errors.  Once you can see the errors, you'll be able to troubleshoot.

Try this:

```
Private Sub client1_DownloadCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs)
    If e.Error IsNot Nothing Then
        Msgbox(e.Error.Message)
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf e.Cancelled Then
        Msgbox("Cancelled")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    koliko = koliko + 1
    Label8.Text = "Popravlja se " & koliko & "/" & odkoliko & " stavka!"
    AllDownloadFinished()
End Sub
```

More Info:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.asynccompletedeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.asynccompletedeventargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I changed the code like you said and it's showing error:
"Argument 'Prompt' cannot be converted to type 'String'."

Now I need to figure out which one is error... :/

Comment: I've edited to correct a typo from Msgbox(e.Message) to Msgbox(e.Error.Message)

Comment: I changed it and compiled successfully. Then when I run program it shows me this error: "Argument 'Prompt' cannot be converted to type 'String'." Do you know where is the problem?

Comment: Adding "Option Strict" as the first line of your code might give you more useful errors.  I'd need to see the relevant source code to help further.

Comment: I fixed it by adding e.Error.ToString and now I got this "an exception occurred during a webclient request access to the path is denied"

Comment: FOUND FIX! Cuz I made app to install with installshield, permissions of the installation folder were limited. I made every app to run automatically as adminsitrator. Problem is solved! Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear it!  If this was the answer, please mark it =)